# How set options for a NSIS uninstaller

Tags: nsis

I have an NSIS installer with some options which works very well. But my "--quiet" option doesn't work for the uninstaller.

```
        uninst:
          ClearErrors
${getOPtions} $CMDLINE "--quiet" $0
${IfNot} ${Errors}
          StrLen $2 "\Uninstall.exe /S"
        ${Else}
          StrLen $2 "\Uninstall.exe"
    ${EndIf}
          StrCpy $3 $0 -$2 # remove "\Uninstall.exe" 
          ExecWait '$0 _?=$3' ;Do not copy the uninstaller to a temp file`
```

Comment: And does not work means what? Does GetOptions fail or does ExecWait fail?

Comment: The command `"\Uninstall.exe /S"` is never executed, so I think  GetOptions fails

Comment: Finally, I just tried `ExecWait "\Uninstall.exe /S"`in the section but there are errors and uninstall failed

Answer (score 0):

GetOptions expects you to call GetParameters to get the parameters, not $CmdLine:

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

...

${GetParameters} $1
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} $1 "--quiet" $2
${IfNot} ${Errors}
    MessageBox mb_ok "Quiet mode"
${EndIf}
```

`ExecWait "\Uninstall.exe /S"` is never going to work, \Uninstall.exe means Uninstall.exe in the root of the current drive. You must use the full path and it should look something like this:

```
StrCpy $0 "$ProgramFiles\my app" ; TODO: Get the old install path
StrCpy $1 "/S" ; TODO: Set optional parameters
ExecWait '"$0\Uninstall.exe" $1 _?=$0'
```